# Difference between 'this' and normal variable declaration

Tags: javascript, function, this

What is the difference between declaring a variable with `this` in my function than declaring normally using `let` or `var`?

```
const controller = (function() {
  this.name = 'John';
})();

const controller2 = (function() {
  let name = 'Mary';
})();
```

Comment: `this` belongs to objects, it doesn't declare any variables. Also, the provided  examples don't make sense, both controller variables are assigned with `undefined`.

Comment: [This will help you about let and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside your function is `window` object. So you are not creating a variable, you are adding a property to the window object

```js
console.log((function(){return this})() === window)
```

Comment: Assuming strict mode (which you should), it's `undefined` not the global object.

Comment: Right! In such case you get a `TypeError` so it doesn't really makes sense to do that in strict mode